# why response is null when use httppost in my android project?

Tags: android, http-post

i try to send list to server and search in database with this list and create response and reply to client but when i run the program it stop . sometime it work until i stop it .
oftn project stop in this line

```
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

in debug window show this ...

```
Thread [<15> AsyncTask #3] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException)) 
        ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1094  
        ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 569
```

Code:

```
public void onclick_search(View v)
    {

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Sending...", "please wait...",true);
          new Thread(new Runnable() {
              @Override   
              public void run() {
                     postData();                          
                 }
               }).start();


    }
    public void postData() {
        String str = null;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://saynaco.ir/Handler.ashx");

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> item_select = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(6);
            item_select.add(new BasicNameValuePair("land","sale" ));
            item_select.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", city ));         
            item_select.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price",s11 ));
            item_select.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bar",s22));
            item_select.add(new BasicNameValuePair("area",s33));
          item_select.add(new BasicNameValuePair("land_kind", rb));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(item_select));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
             str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
            String []respon = str.split("&");
        if(respon[0] == "ok")
        {


            dialog.dismiss();
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplication(), List_show.class).putExtra("url", respon[1]);
            startActivity(in);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //Intent in= new Intent(getBaseContext(), .class);
            //startActivity(in);
        }
        else {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    } 
     private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
         String line = "";
         StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
         // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
         BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
         // Read response until the end
         try {
          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
            total.append(line); 
          }
         } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
         // Return full string
         return total;
        }
```

Comment: Could you post your entire exception log?

Comment: And you can use `EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())`!

Comment: examp [Android Application] 
DalvikVM[localhost:8602] Thread [<1> main] (Running) 
Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running) 
Thread [<11> Binder_3] (Running)Thread [<12> Binder_4] (Running) 
Thread [<13> AsyncTask #1] (Suspended)  ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(Thread, Throwable) line: 689 
Thread [<14> AsyncTask #2] (Running)Thread [<15> AsyncTask #3] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException)) 
ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1094 
ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 569 Thread.run() line: 856 
  Thread [<16> AsyncTask #4] (Running)

Comment: This is not useful. Please, edit your question with your complete logcat.

Comment: Seems strange that anything in the logcat is shown. There should be all the stacktrace. With this I cannot really help you.. Did you add internet permission to the manifest?

Comment: i write complete code with some changes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907229/why-not-respond-to-me-true-and-stop-android-project

Answer (score 0):

You cannot touch anything in the UI thread from a background thread. So things like:

```
  dialog.dismiss();
```

And

```
  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Cannot be called by the `postData()` which is called by a non-UI thread.

I would recommend using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) , and put everything after this line in the postExecute() method:

```
String []respon = str.split("&");
```

Also read more on this topic: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: i change code to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907229/why-not-respond-to-me-true-and-stop-android-project

Comment: @user2428538 if this answered this question you should mark it as the accepted answer. I will try and answer your other question too.